# What part of sentence is "against which" in this sentence "The new test provides a yardstick against which to measure children's learning."?

Tags: grammar

Why not just say "The new test provides a yardstick to measure children's learning" without the "against which"? What's the meaning or function of this combination? Is it an adjective clause?

Comment: The "against which" emphasizes the test's role as an independently-existing *benchmark*.

Comment: So what's the difference between with and without this phrase?

Comment: user85614, the difference is one of emphasis: the latter emphasizes / underscores the test's independent existence and role as a benchmark; the former does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In your sentence, "against which" is a preposition phrase and, grammatically, it can be omitted without doing any harm to structure. However, as mentioned and explained above,  there may be a subtle semantical difference between them.

Answer (score -1):

These two sentences are very close, and actually denote pretty much the same things, but there is a subtle difference in connotation between them.

> The new test provides a yardstick to measure children's learning.

This sentence creates a strong association between the "new test" and "children's learning".  As if the test were created specifically to measure children's learning.  You might hear something like this spoken by a school administrator praising the values of the new test.

> The new test provides a yardstick against which to measure children's learning.

This sentence creates some distance between the "new test" and "children's learning".  As if, for example, the test were created for some purpose, and it was discovered that it could be used to measure children's learning.  You might hear something like this spoken by a researcher who is evaluating the "new test" and who discovered an application of the test in measuring children's learning.

Comment: There is nothing in the sentence to suggest that the test was created for a different purpose.

Comment: @JimReynolds You are correct that nothing denotes that in the sentence.  But if you look at the connotation of the words, and the context in which similar phrases are used, the implication is clear.